# Debugging Visual Studio linker

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to build an xll addin for Excel using appropriate framwork downloaded from MS website. I am getting the following linker errors:

```
1>FRAMEWRK.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Excel4
1>FRAMEWRK.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Excel4v@16
```

I think that these should be defined in `XLCALL32.LIB` included in the package from MS, but I don't know how to check it. Moreover, added the folder containing this library to the Additional Library Directories, without luck.

Hence my questions:
(1) How can I check what is in `XLCALL32.LIB`?
(2) How can I see which files the linker is using to see if my library is actually included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project properties, Under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, you will see 'Additional Dependencies' - these are the files the linker is using. Assuming that _Excel4 and _Excel4v are defined in XLCALL32.LIB (which I think they are), you simply need to ensure that this file is specified in this list.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers! I thought its enough to give it the directory, thanks for claryfying that you also need to specify the actual file name.